# Expected number of steps until target is reached given that we never go back to 0

Tags: random-walk

I am modeling a biological process using the [Moran model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moran_process) which effectively describes a 1D random walk.

Starting at $i = 1$, the transition probabilities are:

$p_{i, i+1} = \frac{ri}{ri+N} \frac{N-i}{N}$,

$p_{i, i-1} = \frac{N-i}{ri+N-i} \frac{i}{N}$,

$p_{i, i} = 1 - p_{i, i+1} - p_{i, i-1}$,

where if $r > 1$ the random walk is biased towards larger values and the boundaries are $i = 0$ and $i = N$.

Now, given that the random walk doesn't get absorbed at $i = 0$, I'm interested in the expected number of steps until it is absorbed at $i=N$.

Unfortunately, I can't seem to find a derivation of this in the literature and can't derive it myself. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You don't give transition probabilities for state $0$. Does that mean if you're in state $0$ you automatically go to state $1$ on the next step? Or is there some (positive) probability of staying in state $0$ on each step?

Comment: Assume you start from 1 . This's a time-homogeneous Markov Chain . You have $N$ states in total : $1,..,N$ .  Your only absorbing state is $N$ . Build a usual $N\times N$ transition matrix , then remove the final row & column to obtain $(N-1)\times (N-1)$ matrix $Q$ . Your solution is vector $k=[k_i] , i =1,..,N-1$ where $k_i$ is the expected absorption time starting from $i$ . This can be solved from $(I-Q)k = 1_{N-1}$ where $I$ is identity matrix and $1_{N-1}$ is the all-1 vector . If possible you may get $k=(I-Q)^{-1}1_{N-1}$ .

Comment: For more info : [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain#:%7E:text=In%20the%20mathematical%20theory%20of,once%20entered%2C%20cannot%20be%20left.)

Comment: @C.C thanks for pointing out the corresponding wiki. I just googled the wrong terminology.